# Using regex with replaceAll

Tags: java, regex

I have this `regex` which is used to validate phone numbers.

```
^\\(?(\\d{2,3})\\)?[-(). ]?(\\d{2,3})[-(). ]?(\\d{4})$
```

(Yes, I know it is not perfect, but I don't really care). I am just using it to replace phone numbers with another string, say `###` to remove sensitive information. So false positives are fine.

It works when the string I am searching is only a phone number. This works:

```
String PHONE_PATTERN = "^\\(?(\\d{2,3})\\)?[-(). ]?(\\d{2,3})[-(). ]?(\\d{4})$";
String phone = "123-123-1234";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(PHONE_PATTERN, "###")); //prints '###'
```

But with surrounding text it does not work:

```
String PHONE_PATTERN = "^\\(?(\\d{2,3})\\)?[-(). ]?(\\d{2,3})[-(). ]?(\\d{4})$";
String phone = "some other text 123-123-1234";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(PHONE_PATTERN, "###"));
```

By does not work, I mean the text is printed unchanged.

What do I need to change on my regex to get this to work so that the second example prints

```
some other text ###
```

Comment: Holy mother of regex, Batman.

Comment: How did you end up with `^` and `&` *automatically* when building your regex? When I write a regex, I have to actively think about whether either of them should be there, like *"Do I only need to match this at the beginning of strings/lines?"*

Comment: @ADTC I'm a complete noob when it comes to regex. I was just working off what I had found at this site: http://www.zparacha.com/validate-email-ssn-phone-number-using-java-regular-expression/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `^` and `$` from the beginning and end of your expression. Those characters match the beginning and end of a String, but you don't want the phone number to be the only content of the String, so you should remove them.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of anchors `^` and `$` use `\b` (word boundary):

```
String PHONE_PATTERN = "\\b\\(?(\\d{2,3})\\)?[-(). ]?(\\d{2,3})[-(). ]?(\\d{4})\\b";
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the *beginning of string* `^` and *end of string* `$` anchors, with having both of these set you're matching the entire string from the first character in the string until the last character in the string.

- The `^` stipulates the pattern must match the substring **starting** with the *first* character in the string.
- The `$` stipulates the pattern must match the substring **ending** with the *last* character in the string.

If you want to search for a pattern that is at one end or the other, **that is when** you need to use anchors.